# How to download private key certificate Distribucion iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3

I appreciate if someone can guide me about the use of the iOS Distribution Certificates of the Apple development store.
I see that there are already three iOS Distribution certificates created and that this is the limit, therefore I cannot create another one. I have an application that I will upload to the Apple store, but the following error message appears:

**Missing private key for signing certificate. Failed to locate te private key  in the keychain**

My question is, to get that private key, is it possible to download it from the developer store? or how can I get it?

Comment: No, the private key is held in the keychain of the device that created the certificate. You need someone who already has the private key to export it for you.  If you cannot get that key then you will need to revoke one of the existing certificates and request a new one.

Comment: Thanks, another question: If I revoke a certificate, what consequences do I have? Does that affect if I need to update any of the applications that have been signed with the certificate I revoke?

Comment: No, it just means that anyone else with that certificate can no longer submit builds to Apple with that certificate. It doesn't affect existing apps

Answer (score 0):

**Add Private Key**

Within the Keychain Access menu select File > click Import Items. Browse to the .p12 or .pfx file that you want to import and open it. In the Add Certificates window select System in the Keychain drop-down and click Add. Enter your admin password to authorize the changes and click Modify Keychain.

**Creating the iOS Distribution Certificate**

Log in to your Apple Developer account and navigate to Certificates, IDs & Profiles > Certificates > Production.
Add a new certificate.
Set up a certificate of type Production and activate App Store and Ad Hoc.
Click Continue.
To proceed with the next step you need a Certificate Signing Request (CSR).

**Create ".cer" file in iOS developer account**

Login to apple developer account Click “Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles”
Click “Provisioning Profiles”
In the “Certificates” section click “Production”
Click the “Add” (+) button at the top-right of the main panel.
Now, choose “App Store and Ad Hoc”
Click Continue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.